# Solving a non linear equation multiple times with different parameter values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a non-linear equation with a constant 'X'.
I want to obtain the solution of the equation for 10 different values of 'X'.
What is the best way of doing it in MATLAB?

Employing fsolve, I thought of doing this using a loop which runs 10 times. But the problem is that it's not possible to send value of 'X' as a parameter to the function which is called by fsolve (as according to its syntax, fsolve can send only the initial guess value) and which contains the non-linear equation.

This is my MATLAB code:

```
function f = crd(m)
    X=0.1;        %Paramter for whose different values I want to solve the NLE using a loop
    t=(1/(0.8/3600))*log(1/(1-X));
    U=350; P=0.1134; T=165; L=21.415;   %Constants
    a=0.00102*820*2200/(U*P);           %Constant   
    Q=(0.8/3600)*900*exp(-(0.8/3600)*t)*0.9964*(347.3*1000);
    Tmi=60;                             %Constant
    b=m*2200;
    q=(a/t)+(b/L);

    f = ( b - (Q/(T-Tmi)) ) * (b/(L*L*q*q)) - exp(-1/q);
end
```

Changing the value of the parameter 'X' each time, I can use "fsolve(@crd,10)" from the Command Window multiple times. But I want to do this using a loop. 
I want to get solution for X=0.1,0.2,...,0.9,1.0

Comment: Can you share the equation and your code?

Comment: @Aziz, I have edited my question and added the code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to do this is to change your function to accept two parameters: `m` and `X`:

```
function f = crd(m,X)
....
end
```

Then, when you want to call `fsolve`, you can create a temporary function that accepts a single parameter `m`, and pass an actual value for `X` to it. That is:

```
for X = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
    f = @(m) crd(m,X);    % a function that accepts m as input
    sol = fsolve(f, 10);
    ...
end
```

Comment: Regarding the second code snippet in your answer, do I have to inevitably write it in a separate function and run it? Can I give the same commands from the Command Window or somehow include this code in the same MATLAB file? I want the program to be in one MATLAB file only. I don't want to have two functions and hence two .m files.

Comment: You can definitely write this in the Command Window. You don't have to create the temporary function separately. You can do it inside fsolve: `sol = fsolve(@(m) crd(m,X), 10)`. You still need to set `X` either manually or through a loop.